# Export multiple queries from .graphql file

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, gql

I want to export multiple mutation queries from Mutation.graphql

```
mutation CREATE_JOB($input: jobInputType!){
     createJob(input: $input){
      _id,
      address
    }
}

 mutation DELETE_JOB($id: String!){
     deleteJob(id: $id){
      _id,
      address
    }
  }
```

When I have it like this, it complaints,

```
Invariant Violation: react-apollo only supports a query, subscription, or a mutation per HOC. [object Object] had 0 queries, 0 subscriptions and 2 mutations. You can use 'compose' to join multiple operation types to a component
```

How do I export multiple queries from .graphql file?